# Possible to automatically swap URLs when environment goes red on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Sometimes my environment on AWS Elastic Beanstalk goes "red" when the database is stuck on a long query (we're working on that). When it goes red, I'd like all traffic to go into a different environment (or static URL) that contains merely an .HTML file that says "we're in maintenance mode, please wait". Right now, when the environment is "red" it's just a blank screen and creates an even worse user experience.

Is this possible?

Comment: How long is your environment unresponsive during the queries?

Comment: @JamesWing Depends, but could be an hour. Long enough for several customers to notice.

Comment: How about routing the whole site through CloudFront and add custom error pages?

Comment: @RakeshBollampally I prefer not to use CloudFront because we use a wildcard SSL and for that they charge and arm and a leg.

Comment: You can upload your own SSL certificate to cloud front distribution